# OnEditorActionListener called twice with same eventTime on SenseUI keyboard

Tags: android

On just one phone I am testing on (HTC Incredible, Android 2.2, Software 3.21.605.1), I am experiencing the following behavior.

The onEditorAction event handler is being called twice (immediately) when the Enter key on the Sense UI keyboard is pressed.

The KeyEvent.getEventTime() is the same for both times the event is called, leading me to this work-around:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]

    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBox);
    text.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        private long lastCalled = -1;

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ( event.getEventTime() == lastCalled ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                lastCalled = event.getEventTime();
                handleNextButton(v);
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

    [...]
}
```

The EditText is defined as:

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="150sp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtBox" 
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:capitalize="characters" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
    android:autoText="false" 
    android:editable="true" 
    android:maxLength="6"
/>
```

On all other devices I've tested on, the action button is properly labeled "Next" and the event is only called a single time when that button is pressed.

Is this a bug in Sense UI's keyboard, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Thank you for any assistance.

---

Updated - thanks to the answers given, I have settled on the following as my checks. This works fine on both of the phones I have available to test (Sense UI and Cyanogenmod CM7)

```
            if (event != null && event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return false;
            }

            if ( actionId != EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT && actionId != EditorInfo.IME_NULL ) {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: No answer for you I'm afraid, I just wanted to say that I got hit by this issue today. I'd never seen the HTC Sense keyboard before today.. ugh! And how have they got away with ignoring the textNoSuggestions flag? Makes my UI a bit sucky, rot them.

Comment: I've noticed that a lot of apps don't work quite right since their keyboard doesn't implement the default button (it's always "Enter"). This includes Google provided applications (including, I think, the initial registration process). It seems like a pretty big thing for HTC to overlook. 

It's a shame, because I actually like SenseUI over all more than Motoblur.

Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As mitch said, you have to check the event action:

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event == null || event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        return false;

    // do your stuff

    return true;
}
```

This snippet works on both the Sense UI and the emulator.

Comment: This seems to be almost the answer, although on my other phone (running CyanogenMod CM7), "event" is null when I press "Next" on the keyboard, so I have to check for that as well.

Comment: I've also added a 
"if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED)
    return false;"
to the method.

Comment: This didn't solve it for me, @Gene suggestion to return false did. I still check the event action just to be sure

Answer (score 4):

```
(EditText) passwordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
passwordView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    passwordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
            {
                String input;
                if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
                {
                   input= v.getText().toString();
                    Toast toast= Toast.makeText(LogIn.this,input,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if you return true, it means that you are interested in the rest of the events until it reaches IME_ACTION_DONE. So if you return false, it means that you are not interested in the events and that other views will then have the opportunity to handle it. Since you only have 1 view, I suggest you just ignore the actionId check and just return false every time.

```
etMovieName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_movie_name);
etMovieName.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView tv, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("actionId= "+ actionId);
        performSearch();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Other situation is if you have overlapping views or a sibling view, then you can use actionId to pass information around. In this situation, returning true will allow you to pass info to the other view. If you really are interested in the event/actionId (for example if you have another sibling view), then you can do this:

```
etMovieName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_movie_name);

etMovieName.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
etMovieName.setSingleLine();

etMovieName.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView tv, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("actionId= "+ actionId);
        return performSearch();      }
});
```

Notice the actionId value has changed to 6 once I added:

```
etMovieName.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
etMovieName.setSingleLine();
```

Comment: Very strange behavior, but it seems you're exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Gubbel 's answer, I think listen to `ACTION_UP` instead of `ACTION_DOWN` is better, because user can actually tap his finger on the enter key (`ACTION_DOWN`) but then hesitate and hold it to other places.

Normally we want to fire the event only when user release his finger from the enter key.

So the code will be like this:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return true;
            if ((actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL)
                    && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //Do your stuff here
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of sending an ime action and null as an event, it sends a touch event so if your not getting the correct action you can check the event for action_up or action_down

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying here. Is there an event that will work properly on both HTC's Sense UI and other keyboards that properly implement the default action?

Answer (score 0):

Return true;
after handling ur case and it wont be called again

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL)
                {
                    Log.i("here","Add product ");
                    return true;  //this does the trick
                }
                return false;
            }
```